# Http outboundGateway polling

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-integration

Приложение должно опрашивать БД, отправлять полученные сущности в web-сервис и обрабатывать ответ. Удаленному веб-сервису требуется cookie для аутентификации, которую можно получить или обновить вызвав http-endpoint /login. Cookie имеет ограничение по сроку жизни.

```
@Bean
fun compoundTriggerAdvice() = CompoundTriggerAdvice(compoundTrigger(), secondaryTrigger())

@Bean
fun compoundTrigger() = CompoundTrigger(primaryTrigger())

@Bean
fun primaryTrigger() = PeriodicTrigger(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

@Bean
fun secondaryTrigger()= PeriodicTrigger(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

@Bean
fun authMessageSource() = MessageSource<String> {
    GenericMessage("auth-data")
}

@Bean
fun cookieUpdateFlow(cookieStore: CookieStore): IntegrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
    .from(authMessageSource(), Consumer {
        it.poller(Pollers.trigger(compoundTrigger()).advice(compoundTriggerAdvice()))
    })
    .gateway(httpFlow())
    .transform(...)
    .handle(cookieStore)
    .get()

@Bean
fun httpFlow() = IntegrationFlow { f -> f
    .handle(Http.outboundGateway("httpL//localhost:8081/{path}")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .uriVariable<Any>("path") { ... }
        .transferCookies(true)
        .expectedResponseType(String::class.java))
}

@Bean
fun dbFlow(em: EntityManager, cookieStore: CookieStore): IntegrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
    .from(Jpa.inboundAdapter(em).entityClass(TestEntity::class.java)) { it.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) }
    .enrichHeaders {
        it.headerFunction<Any>(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.COOKIE) {
            cookieStore.cookie
        }
    }
    .gateway(httpFlow())
    .transform(...)
    .handle(...)
    .get()
```

1. Cookie обновляется раз в 15 секунд, но если аутентификация завершилась ошибкой, то приложение должно пытаться обновить cookie раз в секунду.
   Проблема в том, что CompoundTriggerAdvice срабатывает при получении сообщения из MessageSource, а не всего flow. Как сделать изменение триггера по окончании обработки?
2. dbFlow не должно стартовать, если cookie еще нет. Можно ли запустить его по событию не прибегая к spel в controlBus и также останавливать, если cookie еще не обновилась, и аутентификация не происходит?
3. Возможно, есть более красивое решение?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что Contol Bus  достаточно хорошо подходит для `Jpa.inboundAdapter()`, что контролировать его активность. Достаточно всего лишь послать команду `stop()` или `start()` для соответствующего бина.

Если такой вариант не устраивает, то можно попробовать реализовать `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` и его `beforeReceive()`, что бы проверить состояние системы перед попыткой вызвать целевой `JpaPollingChannelAdapter`.

Для изменения полиси опроса, можно реализовать что-то на подобие `CompoundTriggerAdvice`, но со своим методом изменения состояния `CompoundTrigger` и вызывать тот метод где необходимо.

Мне юз-кейс не понятен, поэтому я не вижу как оно могло бы быть лучше, но можно посмотреть в сторону `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` и применить его на вот том `Http.outboundGateway`. Или в виде какой-то частоной реализации `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`, когда мы проверяем куки до вызова сервиса и т.д.

Некоторая документация в помощь:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#polling-consumer-change-polling-rate